# Compositions of 4 positive integers summing up to 100

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> Given four positive integers $x$, $y$, $z$, $t$ such that $$x+y+z+t=100$$

Find the number of compositions of $100$ having four positive summands $x$, $y$, $z$, $t$. Note that $x$, $y$, $z$, $t$ do not have to be different.

Comment: This is not clear.  Are you asking "how many $4-$ tuples of positive integers add to $100$" or are you asking something else?  In any case, what have you tried and where are you getting stuck?

Comment: rearranging $4$ things can be done in $24=4!$ ways

Comment: I'm asking the former. I've tried fixing $x$ and calculating the number of permutations for $y$,$z$ and $t$.

Comment: @AmateurMathGuy nit: $4!=24$

Comment: I think you are using the word "permutation" incorrectly.  I think [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes thanks for the correction.

Comment: @stewbasic yes thank you.... I was able to edit it in time...

Comment: @lulu Stars and bars is a technique for counting weak compositions, but not a synonym for them.  Compositions are ordered positive integer summations, and if we want to allow zero summands, we call them *weak* compositions.

Comment: Could you edit the question for me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you have $100$ balls and $3$ plates which is used to divide the balls.

Any permutation of the balls and plates corresponds with a answer to your question, but here $x,y,z,t$ can be zero. To remedy this difference, we can firstly give $x,y,z,t$ a ball respectively. And then, permutate the left $96$ balls and $3$ plates.

So, you will have $$\binom{96+3}{3}=\frac{99*98*97}{1*2*3}=156849$$

Comment: The 4 numbers are positive integers. How can they be zero then ?

Comment: so we can firstly give x,y,z,t a ball respectively

Comment: I like this way of thinking about the problem, as it makes it easy to solve. We can think of the 96 balls as being red, and then three separate balls being green, used as separators. Then we line up the 99 balls and pick which three to paint green and mark as separators. We are *choosing 3 out of 99*. Thinking about it like this helps me at least.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is specifically an example of star and bars problem. We need to find the positive integers $a, b, c, d$ such that $$a+b+c+d=100$$
Using the star and bars method to find number of solutions to this equation we get the number of solutions as 
$$\binom{99}{3} =156849$$

For a reference on Star and Bars method you can visit the following site

https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/